# Corporate Webdesign Manual?

Tags: website-design, client-relations, branding, identity, style-guide

For the Corporate Identity / Brand, there is usually a manual. It is a great deliverable for the client and for me as a student, it is a great way to learn about webdesign.

While there are many websites which host or link corporate identity manuals, I could not find any "webdesign manuals". Is this even a thing?

Does a webdesigner usually create some sort of a document for future use? Or is this more the responsibility of the identity designer?

Would a designer put the ruleset (hierarchie, colors, navigation) of the website into an identity manual?

For some major corporations, I saw just a hint of how the corporate design would affect the webdesign. But usually, they link to a restricted page, so I can not see it.

Do you have resources of "webdesign breakdowns" or guides?

Comment: These are generally called ["style guides"](https://elementor.com/blog/web-design-style-guide/) for things like web sites. And, seeing as they are for the web, they are often set up as a stand alone web page.

Comment: They are also called "design systems" which can further help you in your search for info.

Comment: As for this question, it has a lot of questions within it and isn't really focused enough for StackExchange.

Comment: Which platform would you recommend, if not StackExchange? I thought "Graphic Design Stack Exchange" would be a good fit since it has to do with graphic design?

Comment: If you were asking one question about this topic it'd be fine. As it is, you're asking many.